# Как прочитать видео стрим, получаемый по протоколу UDP

Tags: udp, streaming

Есть камера Panasonic HC-V380, нужно каким то образом прочитать видео, которое она транслирует. Передача идет через WIFI. На данный момент удалось получить данные в виде обычного потока байтов. На сколько мне известно, любой видео файл сначала сжимается на стороне камеры и только потом передается. Вопрос в следующем - как прочитать такой поток или как минимум определить какой формат сжатия используется?

Comment: ffmpeg с 99% вероятностью прочитает этот поток

Comment: Судя по всему мне попался этот 1% потому что при попытке прочить с помощью ffmpeg выдается ошибка invalid data found when processing input

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился. Оказалось, что UDP пакет состоит из JPEG изображений(я). Т.к во всех пакетах присутствуют маркеры 0xFFD8 , 0xFFD9.